# preg_match: What if there're html entities?

Tags: php, regex

I got this function:

```
preg_match("/öppet/iu", $string);
```

What if the "ö" is written as a html entity? Like this: `&ouml;` or `&Ouml;`
Is there a way to find them as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just [decode HTML entities](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) before matching:

```
preg_match("/öppet/iu", html_entity_decode($string));
```

This has the benefit of working for other characters as well, e.g. if you want to match `ä` too at some point in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
preg_match("/(?:ö|&ouml;)ppet/iu", $string);
```

The `?:` prevents the match from being captured to save memory, the `|` is "or"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a PHP version below 5.4.0 you have to specify the use of the UTF-8 encoding:

```
preg_match("/öppet/iu", html_entity_decode($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));
```

Hope this will help.